# It seems my client thought my contract was up a few days before it actually was. Now telling me just to invoice for the rest

Tags: salary, termination, contractors

I had been working for a contractor who needed help with a client of his. He had made a renewal offer for my contract but then rescinded it (apparently it was a joint decision with the client). It was rather abrupt and the first thing I noticed was I was no longer able to login to any of my accounts. I was lucky enough to have an exit interview. I pointed out that my first contract still had a few more days left and 2 weeks must be given to terminate the contract. They said just to invoice them for the remaining few days. I'm not really comfortable with this. I'm wondering if I need to do any ass-covering in my final invoice? What should it say since I'm not actually going to be doing any work? My contract says I would give a detailed invoice with the description of the service on a certain day each month. Should my final invoice say "as per discussed, this cost is to cover the remainder of the contract"? Should I include anything else like this official ends the contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should my final invoice say "as per discussed, this cost is to cover
> the remainder of the contract"?

Yes. Keep it simple. There's no need to complicate matters.

I'm curious, your questions reads as if you're an independent contractor who was performing work for a client on behalf of another contractor. If that's correct, why did you have an exit interview and with whom did you have it?

Comment: I think the situation was rather strange. What you said is correct, we were both independent contractors. He had received budget from his client to hire me to help with his workload. My exit interview was with him. We had to meet so I could return company assets. I wanted an exit interview so I could find out why they rescinded my renewal.

Answer (score 5):

> They said just to invoice them for the remaining few days.

Make sure you have this in writing. If you do, just invoice as asked and call it a day. If it's not in writing, write them an e-mail

> "As discussed in our phone call from [insert_date] I will invoice you for [insert amount] for [insert_service_rendered]. Please let me know if you have any questions or concerns"

Make sure you keep a copy and treat "no response" as silent agreement.